# celery task not running when an object is declared , I am using def save_model function to call celery task as per requirement upon save

Tags: django, django-admin, celery

```
2024-01-29 07:23:52,962: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-16' pid:2871 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2024-01-29 07:23:54,730: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Job: 0.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/asim/Django/Practice-tool-ai-backend/ptenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost
    raise WorkerLostError(
billiard.einfo.ExceptionWithTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/asim/Django/Practice-tool-ai-backend/ptenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost
    raise WorkerLostError(
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Job: 0.
"""
```

The above mentioned is an error I am getting in celery task

I have a requirement to call openai API in django admin save_model function
So when an admin user adds a listening task , I retrieve the transcript and pass it to the openai API to generate questions and store them in database.

Which was previously  workin perfectly fine , since openai takes a lot of time to return response
I put that part of the code in the celery background task to save admin time .. but ran into that issue

More over if i remove that code

```
#tasks.py

@shared_task
def sleeptime(time, obj_id):
    sleep(time)
    try:
        obj = ListeningTask.objects.get(id=obj_id)
        # Continue with processing using the retrieved object
        transcript = obj.transcript
        print(transcript)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print(f"Object with ID {obj_id} does not exist.")
```

and just leave the function with sleep(time)
and call that function in the admin.py
and run the celery task
celery -A PracticeToolAI worker -l info

it again runs successfully

I tried to solve this problem by using sleep(10) function temporarily as I was expecting that the memory error might be because it is accessing the id inside save_model function which is yet not saved maybe
but still the error is there